# capturing variable names passed into a function in matlab

Tags: matlab, function, parameter-passing

Is there a way to grab the name of a structure that is passed into a function in matlab from within the new function.

Example:

```
y = fnX(StructName) % call function



function[y] = fnX(name)

% here is where I want to capture StructName as char text.

end
```

It seems that the structure is renamed and the original name is lost within the function.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`inputname`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/inputname.html).

```
function[y] = fnX(name)

% here is where I want to capture StructName as char text.
StructName = inputname(1);

end
```

Answer (score 2):

The best suggestion I can give, is not to depend on the name of a variable.

It is possible by means of `inputname`, but it would be much more natural to let the name, or any information that you are interested in, be stored in the variable. For example by adding a field to the struct.

This should allow for more code flexibility and reusability and probably improve readability in the meantime.